# How do I make an absolut positioned touchable element on top of a FlatList catch only press events and let other events propagate to the FlatList?

Tags: react-native, event-bubbling, pointer-events, event-propagation, panresponder

I have a `FlatList` in React Native with fullscreen image and video items (with `pagingEnabled`). I want to have a short descriptive touchable text floating on top of the `FlatList`, to open up a view with some information about the image/video when pressed.

To make the user experience nice, I'd like to be able to scroll the `FlatList` through the touchable text as well. I.e. if the user happen to start their scrolling motion on top of the text, the `FlatList` would scroll but if it is a simple press event I'd like to open the view with details about the image/video.

No mater what I try I end up with either the text being able to react to the press OR the `FlatList` being able to scroll. I have tried different configurations with a custom `PanResponder` and `pointerEvents` but seem to always end up with a state were one thing does not work. Do you guys have any smart ideas? I am probably just stuck in the wrong train of thought.

This is a simplified view of my component structure:

```
<View>
  <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 100, zIndex: 10 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('press')}>
      <Text>Some Descriptive Text</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  <FlatList pagingEnabled horizontal {...otherFlatListProps} />
</View>
```